# Web API method parameter considered required when using [CanBeNull]

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0, nullable-reference-types

After migrating one of our apps to .NET 6.0, I've noticed a strange behavior. Here's my method signature (all parameters are passed through query string parameters):

```
[HttpGet("search")]
public async Task<ActionResult<Paginated<Worker>>> SearchAsync(string? name, ...) {...
```

Now, I was using resharper and it was automatically replacing the `?` with the `CanBeNullAttribute`:

```
[HttpGet("search")]
public async Task<ActionResult<Paginated<Worker>>> SearchAsync([CanBeNull]string name, ...) {...
```

I've also had nullable references enabled on the project (`<Nullable>enable</Nullable>`) and I'm using NewsoftJson as my json converter.

After publishing the project, I've noticed that I was getting a 400 when `name` was not set to valid string (ex.: when the url looks like `/search?otherparameter=hhh&...` or `/search?name=&otherparameter=lll`): `The name field is required.`.

Now, I've noticed that:

1. Disabling nullable reference types at the project level makes everything work out
2. Disabling r# replacement of `?` with `[CanBeNull]` while enabling nullable references at the project makes everything work out too.

I always thought that nullable reference types were a static thing, ie, would only be used by the compiler to ensure that null exceptions were a thing of the past. However, the previous behavior disproves that theory, though, since it seems like it's being used my the converter when checking the parameters' values.

Btw, why does resharper insists in replacing the `?` with the `[CanBeNull]` if the results aren't the same?

**edit**: I've found this [link](https://www.dajbych.net/how-c-nullable-reference-types-affects-your-asp-net-core-routing) that confirms the behavior but still no official doc which explain how a static analysis feature ends up changing the runtime behavior..

Thanks.